# Error with no 'message' after promisfying https.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am using ES2017's `await` keyword, and `util.promisify()` to use `https.get()` with `await`.

Testing connecting to HTTPS with the following code:

```
const util = require('util'),
    https = require('https'),
    httpsGet = util.promisify(https.get);

var start = async function(){
    try {
        var res = await httpsGet('https://github.com')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('>>>>>>>CAUGHT AN ERROR>>>>>>', err.message)
    }
    console.log('FINISHED')
}

start()
```

Returns:

```
>>>>>>>CAUGHT AN ERROR>>>>>> undefined
```

I suspect my code is broken, but I'm not sure how. **How can I get a real error?**

**Update**: as requested, just logging err not err.message:

```
>>>>>>>CAUGHT AN ERROR - RAW ERR>>>>>> IncomingMessage {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
```

Comment: does it display something if you log `err` instead of `err.message`? i think error objects have `toString` method called automatically when logged

Comment: what if you log like `(JSON.stringify(err))`

Comment: @Kaddath Added results of logging just `err` above,

Comment: @Kaddath actually that helped me solve it - it's a stream and the function signature of https.get isn't right to be promisified. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback for `https.get` [does not have an `err` option](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback). It's a stream - errors are handled via `.on(error)`. So it doesn't have an `err` callback and can't be used with `util.promisify()`

The only reason an `err` is being shown is that `res` is the **last item** of the callback - which `promisify` expects will be an error. So the `err` thrown here is actually a `res` Stream.

But you can make promise from https.get and without util.promisify:

```
function httpsGet(option) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {                    
    let request = https.get( option, (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
        reject( new Error('Failed to load page'+response.statusCode) );}

        let data = "";
        response.on( 'data', (chunk) => data += chunk );
        response.on( 'end', () => resolve(JSON.parse(data)) );
    } );
    request.on( 'error', (err) => reject(err) );
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the first real answer to the question and deserves to be marked as such. I've combined my answer with your code and marked you as correct. Welcome to Stack!